# Google Sheets formula - dropdown list options linked to time durations and totalled

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm hoping that there is a way to get durations to total up according to statuses determined by the user's selection in a dropdown menu but I don't really know where to start.

Here is the document
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15nduT4-_d9dexBhEeUOtznj96n8tn1ld3CL6OvCvTJU/edit?usp=sharing

So the highlighted durations would become part of the formula for the (currently empty) highlighted cell at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want a total of the duration in seconds, in the table at the bottom, for each of the different statuses.

You can do this with a SUMIF function.  Try this formula in M19:

```
=SUMIF(N4:N16,E19,M4:M16)
```

This checks cells N4:N16 for those equal to E19 (In Progress) and sums the values in M4:M16 for the matching rows.

If this is what you want, you can do the same formula in M20:M24, just changing the E19 to E20, etc.

Note that, if you preferred,  you could also write the formula as:

```
=SUMIF(N4:N16,"In Progress",M4:M16)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is a massive help and the SUMIF way of doing it makes total sense. Many thanks!

Comment: @rozzyaz, if this answer seems correct for your question, please consider also "checking" it, with the checkmark, as a correct answer, to help others in the future.